# Java - Google Calendar API v3 quota with 2 legged Oauth

Tags: java, maven, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I'm using Google Calendar API v3 with Oauth 1.0 and JAVA for my Web Application.

It says on the official website ( https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/pricing )
that the quota is 10 000 queries per day. I've also set up in my Google API console panel a limit of a 100 requests per second per user.

When I ran my test, the calendar API was working fine ( all the operations I was doing in my java application where showing up on my calendar ). Then when I hit around 50 operations I got a 403 Forbidden, quotaExceeded error.

Does anyone have the same issue ?

Thanks

EDIT :

The exact JSON error I get from google is :

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
 "code" : 403,
 "errors" : [ {
"domain" : "usageLimits",
"message" : "Quota Exceeded",
"reason" : "quotaExceeded"
 } ],
"message" : "Quota Exceeded"
}
```

The google calendar maven dependency in my project :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-calendar</artifactId>
        <version>v3-rev7-1.6.0-beta</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have been there, see this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-apps-marketplace-api/l1BaiNPpGw8)...

Or you sure that your API console is related to your Google Apps project and the used OAUTH consumer key/secret ? There is a difference between a API console for use with ordinary Google accounts and Google Apps accounts. You must create a Google Apps marketplace listing, that will automatically create a new API console that relates to the OAUTH consumer key/secret that you receive from the marketplace.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hey Koma, thanks for your answer. I'm developing a web app though so I'm don't have a marketplace listing on google apps. I do have a Google Apps for business account though. ( the Free version )

Comment: Yes, but you do need to somehow link your OAUTH key/secret to the api console.. the only way I succeed was by having a private listing (you dont have to publish, can be for internal use only... i.e. for your GAPPS for Business).

Comment: Apparently it's linked since I can see in my API Console the requests made with my OAUTH key/secret showing up